# rbenv: install ruby out of home-directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu-14.04, rbenv

I'm trying to install Ruby + Rails on Ubuntu 14.04. I need more than one user to have access to Ruby, so I installed rbenv with ruby-build in the `/opt/.rbenv` directory. Is that right?

If I try to install a version of Ruby using

```
rbenv install 2.1.3
```

it is installed in `~/username/.rbenv/versions`, not in `/opt/.rbenv/versions`.

I don't want to give the second user access to the other user's home directory.

How can I install Ruby in `/opt/.rbenv`? Or is there another solution?

Comment: The whole point of using rbenv, is to let people be in charge of their Ruby environment, including freely adding new Rubies, and removing them. If you're not familiar with administering a Linux system, which is more involved than just using one, you should ask for help from someone who is more experienced. Also, rbenv is designed for a single user; It *can* be used for multiple users but that wasn't its purpose. For multiple users, you might want to consider using RVM, which does support multiple-user installations. Completely read [the RVM installation page](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) first.

Comment: You can use rvm and install it for each one of the users separately, as virtual environments.

Comment: @theTinMan I'm sure you meant well, but they way you said "...you should ask for help from someone who is more experienced" did sound a bit dismissive, unhelpful even. Mind that @luklapp is doing exactly that on Stack Overflow: seeking the advice of people with experience. He's here to learn, you can help. Also to suggest `rvm` is a non-solution to his question.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `RBENV_ROOT` environment variable:

```
sudo RBENV_ROOT=/opt/.rbenv rbenv install 2.1.3
```

See [documentation](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#environment-variables).